# Maximum table comment length for Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

What is the maximum length for a table comment in Oracle and SQL Server? For MySQL this is 60 chars.

Comment: SQL Server has no "real" (SQL based) object comments. You need to use "extended properties"

Comment: [And 7,500 bytes is the limit for extended properties.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180047.aspx)

Comment: The column description property is a sql_variant, meaning it can hold 8000 bytes, but I believe @a_horse_with_no_name is right that you need to use extended properties to hold table-specific information.

Comment: @RussellFox the limit is 7500 bytes - this is not set by the SQL_VARIANT part but by the sp_addextendedproperty stored procedure.

Comment: I meant the preexisting column description, not an extended property (though it could well be true for both).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search lead to the comments being stored in user_tab_comments, so just check the size of that column in your DB.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle limit on comment size is 4000 characters.